# Do TAA members have to use TAA lease contract?

Tags: residential-lease, texas, taa

It appears that the **TAA *Apartment Lease Contract*** could only be used by a **TAA Member**.

However, what about the other way -- does a TAA Member have to use the TAA Lease Contract?

Comment: Note: this is a sub-question based on a claim at http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/917/can-texas-landlords-charge-administrative-fee-twice-thrice, where I felt like it made sense to equate "TAA members" and the lease contract sanctioned by their org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template leases and other such forms fall under the moniker of association member services.  I don't have a copy of the association's bylaws but can't imagine how membership in the association would imply forfeiting the right to enter into a valid contract of one's own choosing (*i.e.* one that satisfies mutual assent, offer & acceptance, consideration, capacity, and legal purpose).

**Edit:**  In *Texas Apartment Association v. U.S.*, 869 F.2d. 884 (5th Cir. 1989), para. 6 states "TAA's bylaws prohibit local affiliates from marketing competing forms or manuals, although some members prepare documents for their own use."

Comment: That's a good start, but TAA is quite huge here in Texas (as a tenant, I've never heard of anything like it in NorCal or anywhere else), so, could you perhaps find their bylaws, and provide a more definitive answer?

Comment: @cnst I'm not a member, however you might try contacting them directly to request a copy.  Also, see the case law edit above.

Comment: That case law is a good read!   Also interesting that's TAA is 60% strong, oh my!  The forms are definitely not as prevalent, at least when you count the larger corporate landlords, although I guess they skew the results as 300+ units would count as a single member.   "TAA membership is open to owners of multi-family units and service companies who pay annual dues of $35; its members operate about sixty percent of Texas' multi-unit rental housing."